# Get Phone number info including '-' when customer type without '-'

Tags: shipping-address

If a customer type phone number like 2319272918,

Is there any way the phone number data is save like 231-927-2918? including - as I want

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses `Prototype library to manage form validation of  input fields`. This comes in handy, because `all you need to do when writing custom form is to assign a valid class names to your input fields`, and pass the form id to VarienForm object.

you need add  `css class validate-phoneStrict at field` which will do this type validation. you need to remove `validate-number` etc validation

You need see js field validation at `js\prototype\validation.js`

```
      <input type="tel" name="shipping[telephone]" 
    value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>"
     title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="validate-phoneStrict
     input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>"
 id="shipping:telephone" />
```

see [at](http://www.phpcmsframework.com/2014/04/prototype-javascript-validation-in.html) http://www.phpcmsframework.com/2014/04/prototype-javascript-validation-in.html